# DI, is it a bad sign to add an object just to hand it on?

Tags: php

```
class A
{
    public function doIt($c)
    {
        if (rand(0,1) == 1) // this means, we dont know if we need to create the object or not
        {
             $b = new B($c);
        }
    }
}

class B
{
}

class C
{
}

$c = new C();
$a = new A();
$a->doIt($c);
```

the problem is, `A` doesnt need to have `$c` or knowing about `C`. Still, we have to pass it just to handle it on `B`. Isnt it a bad sign? I think it is, since `A` has nothing to do with `B`.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you create instance of `C` inside of `if` in `A` ? There would be about 50% instances of `C` less.

Comment: What will you do with `$b` later on?

Comment: What does the random part have to do with the question? I don't think the presence or absence of that `if` statement makes any difference to the core of the question: is it bad design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could improve on this by employing a [dependency injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern. That way the `A` instance does not need to know about `$c`, or even how to create a `B` instance.

Instead you would provide the `A` instance with the *injector* function, i.e. a callback that `A` needs to call in order to get an instance of `B`.

This way you also don't lose the advantage you had in the original code: the instance of `B` is only created when needed. But this advantage is also extended to the creation of the `C` instance: it is only created when needed:

```
class A {
    public function doIt(Callable $factory) {
        $b = 'nothing';
        if (rand(0,1) == 1) {
             // Call the callback to get the B instance:
             $b = $factory();
        }
        // other code...
        //
        return $b;
    }
}

class B { }

class C { }

$a = new A();
$b = $a->doIt(function () {
    $c = new C();
    return new B($c);
});
var_dump($b);
```

Note: if you need `A` only to do such type of things, then you may consider creating the `doIt` method as a `static` method. Then you would not need to actually create an instance of `A`:

```
class A {
    public static function doIt(Callable $factory) {
       // ...etc
}
// ...

$b = A::doIt(function () {
    return new B(new C());
});
```